# Sum of the number 1 to 1000 using MPI

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

The summation is 49995000 in this case, but it should be 50005000. The number 10000 is missing. The following code makes use of 10 processors to compute the sum of numbers ranging from 1 to 1000. This aggregate is calculated by each of the processors, and the results are shown on the screen.

The final result of all processors' computations is gathered and aggregated by the zero processor, and the final result is shown in the output of the program.

I didn't figure out what the problem is. Please assist me in this matter.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <mpi.h>

static int rank, nodes;

int main()
{
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &nodes);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Status status;

    int ans = 0;
    int total = 0;

    int start = rank * 1000;
    int end = start + 999;

    for(int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        ans = ans + i;
    }

    if(rank != 0) {
        MPI_Ssend(&ans, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    } else {
        total = ans;
        for(int j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
                MPI_Recv(&ans, 1, MPI_INT, j, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
                total += ans;
        }
        printf("Total is %d\n", total);
        printf("Total Nodes is %d\n", nodes);
   }


    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

The PBS Job file as followers,

```
#PBS -l nodes=2
#PBS -l walltime=00:02:00
#PBS -l select=10
cat $PBS_NODEFILE
NPROC=10
cd $PBS_O_WORKDIR
MPISIZE=$NPROC
MPIPROG=`basename $PBS_JOBNAME .pbs`
echo 'Running MPI program' $MPIPROG 'on' $MPISIZE 'processes'
echo 'Started at' `date`
echo '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
(time mpirun -n $MPISIZE ./$MPIPROG) 2>&1
echo '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
echo 'Finished at' `date`
```

Comment: this is because you are summing numbers from `0` to `9999`. As a side note, I strongly encourage you to take 2 minutes to read about `MPI_Reduce()`.

Comment: It sounds like you want to implement a map-reduce logic.for(int j = 1; j < 10; j++) loops 9 times.

Comment: Thank you very much Gilles. I modified like this, int start = rank * 1000 + 1; Then it works now. Thank you again. Also, I read about MPI_Reduce(). Thank you for your advices. ☺